# Get item image inside email

Tags: product, php, product-images

We use a email template with the following code.
We want to extend this with the product image, but that does not seem to work.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getOutOfStockItems()->getData() as $item): ?>
<?php echo $item['name'] ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I already tried `<?php echo $item['image'] ?>` But that does not seem to work.

How can I get the product image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getOutOfStockItems()->getData() as $item): ?>
    <?php echo $name  = $item['name']; ?>
    <?php echo $image = $item['image_url']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

EDIT:

Try to print what you have in your object and look if you have this **image** like this:

```
<?php Zend_Debug::dump($this->getOutOfStockItems()->getData()); ?>
```

To load the product by the product ID:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly that does not seem to work. I do not get any result.

Comment: Look my explanation

Comment: Thanks, but there is no image. So I think I should get it using the sku, right? Can you help me out with the right code?

Comment: Have you the productID in the getData() ??

Comment: Yes product ID is also in the getData, by 'product_id'.

Comment: You can look now

Comment: Thanks a lot! But whats is the best way in that case by loading the image inside the may? So loading a small version of the product image.

Comment: yes, you can get the `getThumbnailUrl()`